# Finding the correct formula for encoded hex value in decimal

Tags: delphi, math, hex

I have a case here where I am trying to figure out how a hex number is converted into a decimal number.

I had a similar case before, but found out that if I reversed the hex string, and swapped each second value (little-endian), then converting it back to a decimal value I got what I wanted, but this one is different.

here is the values we received

Value nr. 1 is
Dec: 1348916578
Hex: 0a66ab46

I just have this one decimal/hex for now but I am trying to get more values to compare results.

I hope any math genius out there will be able to see what formula might been used here :)

thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I think those two values are not equals at all. There is just one way to write hex numbers in that format, the Windows calculator will give it to you. Are you sure this is not base 64 or something ? (Edit it's not that either).

Comment: Why don't you tell us where you got these values from?

Comment: Not only where you get those values from, why do you think they're equal? Are you sure there's no copy-paste error in the numbers?

Comment: I think they may be equal somehow, as when I express each in binary, I observe that they each have 14 1s.

Comment: I got the numbers from a card a client sent me, the decimal number is printed on the card, and the software reading the card (This is an EM RFID card) output the hex value. I just got one card, I will be trying to get an additional card

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
1348916578
= 5    0    6    6     D    5    6    2 hex
= 0101 0000 0110 0110  1101 0101 0110 0010

0a66ab46
= 0    A    6    6     A    B    4    6 hex
= 0000 1010 0110 0110  1010 1011 0100 0110
```

So, if a number is like this, in hex digits:

```
AB CD EF GH
```

Then a possible conversion is:

```
rev(B) rev(A) rev(D) rev(C) rev(F) rev(E) rev(H) rev(G)
```

where `rev` reverses the order of bits in the nibble; though I can see that the reversal could be done on a byte-wise basis also.

Comment: did this work for you? how did you implement it codewise in delphi. possible to do this in php?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting....  I expanded the decimal and hex into binary, and this is what you get, respectively:

```
1010000011001101101010101100010
1010011001101010101101000110
```

Slide the bottom one over by padding with some 0s, then split into 8-byte blocks.

```
10100000 1100110 11010101 01100010
10100    1100110 10101011 01000110
```

It seems to start to line up.  Let's make the bottom look like the top.

Pad the first block with 0s and it's equal.
The second block is ok.
Switch the 3rd block around (reverse it) and 10101011 becomes 11010101.

```
10100000 1100110 11010101 01000110
```

Likewise with the 4th.
    10100000 1100110 11010101 01100010

Now they're the same.

```
10100000 1100110 11010101 01100010
10100000 1100110 11010101 01100010
```

Will this work for all cases?  Impossible to know.

Comment: wow, strange, maybe this is something, I will however need to get an additional decimal/hex to check this

Comment: interresting enough, the first one 10100 might be 000101000 since binaries wont really display values starting with 0

Comment: I have upvoted Barry's answer as it is a nice implementation of my observations.

Comment: I created an delphi implementation of this if anyone interrested I can provide ot

Comment: im interested in delphi implementation!

Answer (score 0):

The decimal value of x0a66ab46 is 174500678 or 1185637898 (depending which endian you use, with any 8, 16 or 32bit access). There seems to be no direct connection between these values. Maybe you just have the pair wrong? It could help if you posted some code about how you generate these value pairs.

BTW, Delphi has a fine little method for this: SysUtils.IntToHex

Comment: I am aware of the delphi's inttohex :) used it in prior projects

Answer (score 0):

What we found was that our min USB reader that gave 10 bit decimal format is actually not showing the whole binary code. The hexadecimal reader finds the full binary code. so essentially it is possible to convert from hexadecimal value to 10 bit decimal by taking off 9 characters after binary conversion.

But this does not work the other way around (unless we strip away 2 characters from the hexadecimal value the 10 bit decimal code will only show part of the full binary code).

So case closed.

Comment: this issue was solved :)))) but I might get other cases on other codes, Thanks :-)

Comment: the rev function is something that maps numbers to their binary reverse; so rev(1) = rev(0001b) => 1000b = 8, rev(2) = rev(0010b) = 0100b = 4, rev(5) = rev(0101b) => 1010b = 10, etc. You can make a lookup table or even a switch statement for all the cases. Combining and separating out the bits, you do with shifting and masking.